# Permission denied to copy database

Tags: postgresql, roles, postgresql-9.5

I'm still getting used to the concept of roles in Postgres.

I'm trying to create a role, `migrator`, that will have the ability to read from a production db and use it as a template to make stage and dev databases.

I've created this role `migrator` originally like so:

`CREATE ROLE migrator LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '<password>'`

and proceeded to restrict access to the prod database:

```
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE prod FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE prod TO migrator;
/* switch to prod database */
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO migrator;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO migrator;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO migrator;
```

After trying a `CREATE DATABASE stage TEMPLATE prod;` and getting an error, I had to alter the role to create a db:

```
ALTER ROLE migrator CREATEDB;
```

and tried again. This time I got the error: 
`ERROR:  permission denied to copy database "prod"`

And again, I tried to add the replication permission to the migrator role (not sure if this is correct, as the manual says this is a very elevated permission)

```
ALTER ROLE migrator REPLICATION;
```

however, I still get the same error.

**UPDATE:** I've figured out that this has something to do with who owns the database; however, my problem remains. How can I allow another role with just READ privileges the ability to copy a database as well? I looked at role inheritance, but at first glance it looks like the *inheriting* role will just get the same permissions as the parent role.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to copy a database unless the logged-in role is an owner or [the database is flagged as a template](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html):

> datistemplate can be set to indicate that a database is intended as a template for CREATE DATABASE. If this flag is set, the database can be cloned by any user with CREATEDB privileges; if it is not set, only superusers and the owner of the database can clone it.